# Distribution of $e^{jX}$, where $X$ is uniform on $(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: probability-theory, complex-numbers, uniform-distribution

$X \sim \mathcal{U}\left( { - \pi ,\pi } \right)$, $\mathcal{U}$ is uniform distribution, $Y = {e^{jX}}$, $j$ is unit imaginary number. How do I get the distribution of $Y$ , the expected value of $Y$ ($EY = ?$) and the variance of $Y$ ($DY = ?$)

I calculate it as  $EY = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{e^{jx}}dx}  = 0$, $DY = E{Y^2} - {\left( {EY} \right)^2} = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{e^{j2x}}dx = 0}$. But $EY = DY = 0$ seems strange. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[Y]=0$ makes sense from a geometric perspective: your points are uniformly distributed on the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, so they average out to nothing.

Your variance calculation is wrong. A better way to do the calculation rather than splitting is to fall back on $E[|Y-E[Y]|^2]$, where in this case the absolute value bars denote the modulus. So in this case you need to compute $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |e^{ix}|^2 dx$, which is not zero.

By the way, your title would be clearer if it referenced the fact that you're dealing with a *complex* exponential rather than a real exponential.